# Access MySql database on the Server A from PHP mysqli on Server B with different PHP version

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, remote-access

I'm trying to figure out, how is possible to retrieve records from `MySql` database tables, located on the **server A**, which is `PHP Version 5.3.29` from  **server B** `php` `mysqli` `PHP Version 7.2.8`

I found this example [How to Connect to the Remote MySQL Database using PHP](https://www.codexworld.com/connect-access-remote-mysql-database-cpanel-php/), but I don't understand, how it works in relation to what I'm trying to do, doubt if it is what I'm looking for

I'm new with `php`, and all that I can imagine, I should be to use connection data from **server A** for `php mysqli` on **server B**,  and add `access host IP` of **server B** in `Remote MySQL` of **server A**, and seems like I have to add database user and password in `MySQL databases` on **server A**, but I'm not sure, where do I have to get it on  **server B**

**Server A**:

Version by `phpinfo();`:  `PHP Version 5.3.29`

> Database server
>
> ```
> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
> Server type: MySQL
> Server version: 5.6.39 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
> Protocol version: 10
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
> ```
>
> Web server
>
> ```
> cpsrvd 11.70.0.51
> Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
> PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
> PHP version: 5.6.30
> ```
>
> phpMyAdmin
>
> ```
> Version information: 4.7.7
> ```

**Server B**:

Version by `phpinfo();`:  `PHP Version 7.2.8`

> Database server
>
> ```
> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
> Server type: MariaDB
> Server version: 5.5.56-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
> Protocol version: 10
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
> ```
>
> Web server
>
> ```
> nginx/1.11.10
> Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - $Id: 
> PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
> PHP version: 5.6.30
> ```
>
> phpMyAdmin
>
> ```
> Version information: 4.6.6
> ```

Any advice, guide or example would be very helpful

**Edit:**

My attempt by answer, first of all I've added `IP` of **server B** in `Remote MySQL` on **server A**. My `conn.php`, located on **Server B** to connect to **Server A**:

```
<?php
$servername = "Server_A_IP";
$username = "Server_A_database_user";
$password = "Server_A_database_user_password";
$db = "Server_A_database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

if(!$conn)
{
    die ("Error on the Connection" . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

and `dbtab.php` also located on **Server B** with `conn.php` in same folder:

```
<?php
 include 'conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <h1 align="center">Database</h1>
    <table border="1" align="center" style="line-height:25px;">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Records</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#ff897f">id</td> 
    <th bgcolor="#ff897f">name</td>   
    </tr>
<?php
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
    ?>
     <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#e5cac8"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#e5cac8"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <?php
   }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">There's No data found!!!</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but in result, when I'm tying to open `www.site.com/folder/dbtab.php` or `www.site.com/folder/conn.php`, page does not load, just freezes

ping of **Server A**:

[image]

Comment: I think more important is what version of mysql you have on both servers (?)

Comment: Unless you're building an API to abstract the database layer, PHP does not matter on Server A.  You'd just want to connect directly to the MySQL server on the remote server...

Comment: @Edwin Hello, I've edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need php on Server A for this. You just need to configure your MySQL Server (Server A) to

1. allow network access (via IP-addresses) and
2. create a MySQL Account for the IP-address of Server B

If you have set up this you can create a connection from php on Server B by using

`$mysqli = new mysqli("<IP of Server A>", "user", "password", "database");`

see the excellent php website on this: [mysqli Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

The steps 1, 2 depend on your MySQL Server. If you have direct root access you need to edit the configuration files and allow networking, otherwise it depends on the hosting service.

To create a user account with remote access issue the following SQL statement (or use a web GUI):

`GRANT <Rights> ON <db-name>.* TO 'username'@'<IP of Server B>';`

see the MySql manual on granting privileges to users: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Comment: Hello, I have tried to follow your guide, and I've edited my question, please check, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: To answer your edit: you've a typo in dbtab.php. Line 4 is missing an n in the variable name of `$conn` ;)

Comment: yes, but typo was only in this post, on server I have same `conn` in both documents,  I've checked, same result. Seems like it is not the reason of failure, and sometimes I got Error 504 after long time of loading  =(

Comment: Ah, I see. Then this sounds like a connection error. Maybe some firewall is blocking access to Server A? Try pinging it from Server B and if this works see, if you can connect to the MySql Port (typically 3306) e.g. by `nmap -p 3306 <server A>`

Comment: @M. Biegert I've added ping result connect failed  with `telnet www.mysite.com 3306`

Comment: Is this a hosted MySQL instance? In this case you should contact your hosting provider. If the MySQL instance on server A is intended only for Server A (that's what it's looking like) then you cannot connect directly to it from Server B. In this case you indeed need to make an abstraction layer with for example php, which you can query from the web. But then your task gets a whole lot more involved since you need to make sure that requests are authenticated and you don't have any SQL injections.
If you reach this point it might be worth considering rethinking the setup you have in mind.

Comment: @ M. Biegert well, I think, I have to mark your answer, because this failure appears with particular servers **A** and **B**, but same scenario works with another from **Server B** to **Server C**, I have to figure out what is wrong with **Server A**, seems like it is firewall, but I'm not able to access settings. Thank you for support